# ShareLaTeX or OverLeaf templates to write a book to be self-published on Amazon

Tags: technical-writing, self-publishing, kindle, amazon, latex

I'm planning to write a book and eventually self-publish it online through Amazon (I haven't decided which platform on Amazon yet, but Kindle seems reasonable). The book will contain mostly texts, but a few diagrams, Math symbols written in, and possibly some codes in the format `a=0`.

Now, I've used ShareLaTeX/[OverLeaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tagged/book/page/1) for writing articles before and it seems to give me nice printouts, with the Math symbols. I was wondering - Is it advisable to use a book format from ShareLaTeX/[OverLeaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tagged/book/page/1) to write a book for amazon that contains texts, math symbols, and codes?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using LaTeX for your purposes is that it doesn't really translate well to ebook formats—it carries a lot of baggage from its print origins and so while you can create PDF files (which can be viewed on the Kindle), they aren't necessarily the best option.

That said, technical material tends to suffer in presentation on most ereaders when it's attempted to be presented in the native format (largely, I suspect, because of the mismatch between the needs of technical typesetting and the capabilities of the formatting with too many of the tools that handle technical material well doing a poor or non-existent job at outputting to the HTML subset that's the basis of ePub or Kindle's mobi format), so perhaps PDF isn't such a bad option, as long as you tune your template towards the reader screen rather than a printed page (which will call for non-standard page dimensions, etc.). I would suggest going to the TeX stackexchange for help with those sorts of details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is!

LaTeX provides several standard `documentclass`es, [`book`](https://ctan.org/pkg/book), [`report`](https://ctan.org/pkg/report), [`article`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/article), [`memoir`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir), and many more custom ones, depending on the final format one wants to achieve.

On [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) many templates are shared, and most of these are based on the above documentclasses. Several "book" templates are made with `report` documentclass and additional packages to implement any tipographic rule.

If you search on Overleaf or other networks ([this](https://www.latextemplates.com/cat/books) is one), you will find custom documentclasses and templates oriented on text, equations and math, but also tables, charts and diagrams.

It is important that you find one template to use (or to edit before use) in order to implement the specifications that you are given for your book or publication, starting from the most basic geometries (page dimensions, margins, etc.) to the very detail if necessary.

To handle respectively references and diagrams, packages such as [`hyperref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and [**TikZ**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) may be useful, if you have time to develop.

Anyway, remember that LaTeX remains a markup language, so try to opt for an empty box or template whose code you can handle. For example, after years, even I am still trained for hi-level LaTeX language but I never got very skilled in the lower-level TeX language; for this reason I still skip the templates with too many `@`s that would exceed my technical knowledge. Stay focused on contents and choose a template to most simplifies your typing.

Here is another [Amazon KDP oriented template form Overeaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/book-template-for-amazon-kdp-and-google-play-e-book-and-pdf/dypgzfzmhnmc).